# Error with Openerp 6.01 installation in CentOS

Tags: python, centos, odoo, kloxo

I am new in openerp.

when installing process of openerp 6, i want to generate a config file with this command,

cd /home/openerp/openerp-server/bin/

`./openerp-server.py -s --stop-after-init -c /home/openerp/openerp-server.cfg`

but it was always showed a message

`ImportError: No module named psycopg2`

when i check for psycopg2 package, it's already installed,

Package python-psycopg2-2.4.5-1.rhel5.x86_64 already installed and latest version

Nothing to do

what's wrong with this? my server is centos, i've installed python 2.6.7.

Really need your help guys..

Comment: Did you install Python from an external package? Possibly means psycopg2 is not available for the version of Python OpenERP is using.

Comment: so what should i do? do i must reinstall for other version of psycopg2? what version? Please help..

Comment: Provide us with some more information, e.g Have you got versions of Python. Generally use easy_install or pip to install Python packages.

Comment: i use this command : easy_install psycopg2, but an error message happen..

Comment: this is the error..
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

i use python 2.6.7

Comment: have u tried easy_install26? i recommend installing openerp on ubuntu and save yourself some major headaches because centos packages are often out of date. i rememebr when i had openerp on centos with the default python version of 2.4 it caused problems to install similar packages for python 2.6.

Answer (score 0):

Please install the `psycopg2` from http://rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/sourceforge/p/pg/pgbarman/rhel5-deps/python26-psycopg2-2.4.5-1.rhel5.x86_64.html